# How to instantiate a generic array?

Tags: java, generics, instance

I've some issues trying to instantiate an array of templated type :

```
public class MyList<T extends Comparable<T>> {

  private T[] data;

  /**
   * Initializes the list
  **/
  public MyList() {
    data = new T[0];
  }

  // ...
}
```

I assume that the type of T is defined during runtime, isn't it ?

Regards,

Comment: No... it's not.

Comment: No T is erased at runtime. You need to read the java tutorial on generics and erasure to understand why you can’t write new T[0]

Comment: As other's have hinted, the type which T actually stands for is determined at compile time.